# JNI SetFloatArrayElement() not working

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to modify some values in a jfloatArray before returning it to the java Android code. 
I've found that I can't use the regular way `newArray[i] = result[i];` to do it and instead I should do `env->SetFloatArrayElement(newArray,i,result[i]);`.

The problem is that this function throws the error:

> [armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm  : tensorflow_mnist <= tensorflow_jni.cc
>   jni/./tensorflow_jni.cc: In function '_jfloatArray*
>   Java_jp_narr_tensorflowmnist_DigitDetector_detectDigit(JNIEnv*,
>   jobject, jintArray)': jni/./tensorflow_jni.cc:171:14: error: 'JNIEnv'
>   has no member named 'SetFloatArrayElement'
>            env->SetFloatArrayElement(newArray,i,result[i]);
>                 ^

Code:

```
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL
TENSORFLOW_METHOD(detectDigit)(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jintArray raw_pixels) {

    jboolean iCopied = JNI_FALSE;
    jint* pixels = env->GetIntArrayElements(raw_pixels, &iCopied);
    jfloatArray newArray = env->NewFloatArray(2);
    jfloat *result = process( reinterpret_cast<int*>(pixels) );


    for(int i=0; i<2; ++i) {

        //VLOG(0) <<  " (" << i << "): " << newArray[i];
        //newArray[i] = result[i];
        //env->SetFloatArrayElement(newArray,i,result[i]);
     }


    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(raw_pixels, pixels, JNI_ABORT);
    env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(newArray, result, JNI_ABORT);

    free(result);

    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to modify some values in a jfloatArray before returning it to the java Android code. I've found that I can't use the regular way `newArray[i] = result[i];` to do it and instead I should do `env->SetFloatArrayElement(newArray,i,result[i]);`.

What makes you think that?  As the compiler informs you, JNI has no `SetFloatArrayElement()` function.  There is a single-element-setting function only for `Object` arrays, i.e. `SetObjectArrayElement()`.

There are several alternatives for dealing with primitive arrays.

- The classic mechanism is to use the appropriate `Get*ArrayElements()` function to get an ordinary array, modify the array, and then `ReleaseArrayElements()`.  Note also that with this approach, if you want to commit changes (as you do) then you must use mode `0` or `JNI_COMMIT`, not `JNI_ABORT`.
- For quick-running uses such as yours that does not call other JNI functions, you could consider `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()` and `ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical()`.  You should not do that if you do any I/O between the get and release, however.
- For your specific case, however, I would suggest `SetFloatArrayRegion()`.  There is a corresponding `GetFloatArrayRegion()`, but you don't need it because you don't care about pinning or about the initial values of the (Java) array elements.

Using the third alternative might look like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL
TENSORFLOW_METHOD(detectDigit)(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jintArray raw_pixels) {

    jfloatArray newArray = env->NewFloatArray(2);
    jint* pixels = env->GetIntArrayElements(raw_pixels, NULL);

    jfloat *result = process( reinterpret_cast<int*>(pixels) );

    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(raw_pixels, pixels, JNI_ABORT);
    env->SetFloatArrayRegion(newArray, 0, 2, result);

    free(result);

    return newArray;
}
```

If you could rely on the `process()` function running very quickly and without any possibility of blocking, then you could consider using `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()` and `ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical()` to access the pixel array.  It is possible that that would be more efficient on account of avoiding making a copy of the pixel array, but it is by no means certain that the approach you are using already would make a copy. (Note in particular that the second argument to `GetIntArrayElements()` is an *output* variable; it reports on whether a copy has been made, but does not direct that).

Comment: I actually found SetFloatArrayElement() in the JNI reference for Unity3D. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJNI.SetFloatArrayElement.html
Thanks, though. I'm now using SetFloatArrayRegion() instead.

Comment: @BernardoGO, evidently, AndroidJNI does not map 1:1 onto JNI.  I can see how that might come as a surprise.  FWIW, the canonical reference for JNI would be [the one provided by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks